# what's the powershell equivalent to Bourne/Bash -d and -f when testing if a string is a folder or a file?

Tags: powershell

As an example, this Bourne script will output "its a folder" if the string supplied is a folder or "its a file" if it's a file.

```
_test=/home/myuser

if [ -d $_test ]; then
   echo "its a folder"
elif [ -f $_test ]; then
   echo "its a file"
fi
```

`/home/myuser` is home folder for my user acct. The Windows equivalent will be `C:\Users\myuser`

Comment: related information: if you need to do something with all files / directories inside a folder you can filter them like this and don't need to test if it's a file or directory `gci . | ? { $_.PSisContainer }` for directories or `gci . | ? { !$_.PSisContainer }` for files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PowerShell's `Test-Path` cmdlet and its `-PathType {Container|Leaf}` parameter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-5.1)<sup>1</sup> to determine if a path is a directory or a file:

```cs
Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\myuser\FooDir" -PathType Container
# Would throw 'True' or 'False'.
```

The analogy to your bourne-script would therefore be:

```cs
param(
    [string]$ToTest = "C:\Users\myuser\FooDir"
)

if(Test-Path -Path $ToTest -PathType Container){
    Write-Output "Path is a directory."
elseif(Test-Path -Path $ToTest -PathType Leaf){
    Write-Output "Path is a file."
}else{
    Write-Output "Path is non-existent."
}
```

---

Some things about this script:

- `if(Test-Path -Path $ToTest -PathType Container){}` is the shortened version of `if((Test-Path -Path $ToTest -PathType Container) -eq $true){}` - you can therefore also check for `$false` (e.g. `"This path is NOT a directory!"`
- The above way to specify `$ToTest` means *"if no user-input is given, use the specified fallback-value (`"C:\Users\myuser\FooDir"`)"*. Therefore `.\script.ps1 "D:\MyPath` will evaluate `"D:\MyPath"` , while `.\script.ps1` will evaluate the fallback-value (e.g. `"C:\Users\myuser\FooDir"`).

  - You could also use `[string]$ToTest = Read-Host "Please specify a path to
    check"` if you want to have a console prompt for the path as a fallback...
  - ...or omit the fallback-value-setting completely and use
    [`[Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$ToTest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-5.1)<sup>2</sup>
    instead - with this, the script will only work if you specify a path
    when calling the script.

---

All of the above has been tested with PowerShell versions 2 to 5.1.

---

<sup>1</sup> `Get-Help Test-Path -detailed` will show the same information offline.

<sup>2</sup> `Get-Help about_functions_advanced_parameters` will show the same information offline.

Answer (score 1):

#### How do I test if a string is a folder or a file in powershell?

> Use the `Get-Item` cmdlet to get the object represented by the path.
>   Then use the `–Is` operator to see if the object is a
>   `[system.io.directoryinfo]` object or a `[system.io.fileinfo]` object.
>
> Here is an example:
>
> ```
> PS C:\> (Get-Item c:\fso) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
>
> True
>
> PS C:\> (Get-Item C:\fso\csidl.txt) -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]
>
> False
> ```

Source [PowerTip: Using PowerShell to Determine if Path Is to File or Folder](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/08/31/powertip-using-powershell-to-determine-if-path-is-to-file-or-folder/)